# Does fiduciary responsibility exist in Halacha

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, business, torts-damages

Putting aside Dina D’malchuta Dina, is someone  liable for violations of fiduciary responsibility in Halacha. So does Halacha have a notion of fiduciary responsibility (which means not poorly managing money other people have given to you to manage), which one is liable for violating, or no? Is such a notion referenced in the Talmud or Chazal?

Comment: The various types of shomerim and apotropos immediately come to mind...